# How to do date comparision in gremlin?

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, janus

I have a student node with the below props.

```
{hopper=[true], updatedDate=[Fri Sep 16 09:28:40 UTC 2022], userId=[9c40uvdqkjjmcv4c7f4u3m7gpv],  firstName=[Mounika], lastName=[Mandadi], vLabel=[Student]}
```

I need to query out all the student nodes whose updatedDate is less than a given date.

Queries I have tried:

```
 g.V().has("Student","updatedDate",gt("Fri Sep 17 09:28:40 UTC
 2022")).count()
```

This havent worked.
What is the correct way to query?
What index is preferrable for date comparision queries?

Comment: Is the updatedDate property a string? What is the output of g.V().hasLabel("Student").limit(1).values("updatedDate").next().class

Answer (score 0):

You really have two main options when storing dates (timestamps) and you need to compare them. I'll mention a third option at the end.

1. Use actual `datetime` objects from the client programming language (or use the Gremlin `datetime` function if sending queries as text.
2. Use epoch integers (13 or 10 digit), so the time of this answer would be `1663599168`.

You can also use strings if all you need to do is `gt` and `lt` type operations but the strings need to carefully conform to the ISO 8601 standard format; such as : `2022-09-19T14:57Z`

I prefer to use either real `datetime` objects or epoch integers as they are easier to deserialize to code and allow additional operations such as subtraction to find timestamp deltas.